# Information exchange between two computers connected over wireless

Tags: c, sockets, networking, ssh, tunneling

I would like to get some ideas on this topic which is new for me and i am interested to learn more on this.

I have developed a voice controlled application which is written in C program which should control some operation. I want to control these operations on another computer connected over wireless network.

I want to do the following,

when my voice is recognized at Computer A with a "String A", It should send this "String A" to COmputer B, Computer B sends a request to acknowledge to computer A, when computer A send Acknowledge string "Yes" to B, Computer B will execute a operation (for example open the notepad).

PS: Computer A and B, both are Linux, Ubuntu machines

How to start doing this Information exchange? Also provide some useful links along with your suggestions. I am sure it will help me a lot in completing this.

Answer (score 2):

basically you can use socket communications. Write client and server sockets on both the machines. One to Receive command and other one to send commands. Upon Getting the sockets ready (the whole dance of bind, listen etc.,), you kickoff the voice2text module. OnVoice2TextConverted, send the message to other machine via socket. OnReceive at other machine, prepare another message (ack) to send it to request initiator. Define a message structure for mode communication between these two machines(see if you have to serialize or use XML/JSON). when you shout 'enough', detect the voice through your module and tear down the sockets. Intimate this to other party before tear down. Perform clean up.

Comment: I am doing it for first time, although i have expereince with Putty and MPI before. I would like to ask you to share some useful books or links for this purpose. I would follow them.

I dont know who voted -1 but my main purpose here is to collect some references from expertise to start rather than getting exact solution.

Comment: basically you have to chop down the tasks into pieces. identify potential pieces which you aren't clear about. For instance socket communications, develop a small pilot program that exchanges hi<->hello until you hit enter (there sould be tons of examples online on this). Now you have some text to send over network. Try to slowly pull in your voice module and just send your voice messages there. next stage use your level1 code to send replies for every voice message you sent. Then you reached another level. keep adding pieces by pieces, dont take all at one shot